# Magento 1.9.0.1 doesn't append the form key by default inside "getDeleteUrl" but does for "getAddToCartUrl"

Tags: php, forms, magento, url-encoding, magento-1.9

When I did a clean install of 1.9.0.1, and copied over my design files to the new installation, adding to the cart worked fine but deleting products from the cart did not.

I noticed that in core files, that getDeleteUrl uses:

```
public function getDeleteUrl()
{
    if ($this->hasDeleteUrl()) {
        return $this->getData('delete_url');
    }

    return $this->getUrl(
        'checkout/cart/delete',
        array(
            'id'=>$this->getItem()->getId(),
            Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->helper('core/url')->getEncodedUrl()
        )
    );
}
```

and getAddToCartUrl uses:

```
public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array())
{
    if (!$product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($product)) {
        return $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
    }
    $additional = array_merge(
        $additional,
        array(Mage_Core_Model_Url::FORM_KEY => $this->_getSingletonModel('core/session')->getFormKey())
    );
    if (!isset($additional['_escape'])) {
        $additional['_escape'] = true;
    }
    if (!isset($additional['_query'])) {
        $additional['_query'] = array();
    }
    $additional['_query']['options'] = 'cart';
    return $this->getProductUrl($product, $additional);
}
```

If you notice from the above code, getDeleteUrl doesn't append the form key but getAddToCartUrl does, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually asking two questions, even if you're only stating the one.

**Question 1: Why doesn't deleting a product work**

Assuming you're using `"/checkout/cart/delete/id/2504/uenc/[encoded url key]/"`, it really should work. See my response on the second question.

**Question 2: Why is there no form key in the delete link.**

This one is easier, if you check here:
https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php#L490
and here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php#L441

There's no form key needed to remove products. Either it wasn't added because they didn't think it important enough or it was simply forgotten. Regardless, the delete functionality should work fine without a form key.

Comment: well apparently it does work as expected, only my ajax shopping cart html wasn't being updated with the removed items.  i refreshed the cart page manually, and lo and behold it had been removed from the cart.  this was working with 1.7.0.2, so it must be something else with the html not being updated for some reason.  thanks!